# Highcharts: limit number of markers

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to show a data series with quite a large number of points in a fairly small space, [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhG8j/6/). When a datapoint marker is shown on every point the graph is very cluttered and difficult to read. You can remove the markers completely by changing

```
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }  
        }
    }
```

to

```
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }  
        }
    }
```

But I'd like to do something in between these 2 extremes. Is there a way to specify a maximum number of markers that should be displayed, e.g. 20. I don't particularly care which 20 points are marked, but obviously the marked points should be chosen such that the markers are evenly spaced.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can disable markers per point but you have to supply the data as objects, which can be problematic with large quantities of points:

```
series: [{
    data: [
        { y: 29.9 },
        { y: 71.5, marker: { enabled: false } },
        { y: 106.4, marker: { enabled: false } },
        { y: 129.2 }]
    }]
```

Documentation [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data) (see third item).

Answer (score 1):

I advice to take look at Highstock which allows to grouping data.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 5, 
....
```

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce markers by setting min and max range to `xAxis`:

`xAxis: {
  max: 100,
  min: 50
}`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jhG8j/7/

Comment: But this will completely exclude all data outside this range from the graph, I just want to reduce the number of points that are marked

Comment: @Don you have to control markers individually by setting `enabled` property in series (see @ssarabando's answer). Otherwise, use `max` and `min` properties to "zoom" chart to reduce markers in content view.